# Time series forecasting with different starting conditions

Tags: python, time-series, linear-regression, arima

Suppose we have two components/materials, say 'A' and 'B'. When both of these are combined in different ratios it results in a certain property which can be modelled as a time series (Property C).

| Cycle (Time) | Component A | Component B | Property C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 | 20 | 1.078 |
| 2 | 80 | 20 | 1.035 |
| 2 | 80 | 20 | 0.987 |

To predict the property C, I viewed it as a time series forecasting problem. To solve it, I have used ARIMA model which yields good results.
How can I incorporate the ratio of 'A' and 'B' into modelling the time series? Ultimately, I want to predict 'Property C'  with different ratios of 'A' and 'B'.

Comment: This question is unrelated to programming and debugging. It’s about statistics and ML. It belongs on [stats.SE] instead of here, so I’m voting to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have [panel data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_data)

So you maybe incorporate using ARIMAX models. Which ARIMA models with exogenous variables, in your case A and B or A/B.

For examples:

1. https://pyflux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arimax.html
2. https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_sarimax_stata.html